# How to Read multiple rows with multiple records in Inserted in table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, sql-server-2012

I want to create a trigger which will read and store data in variables.

But If `inserted` has more than a row then how will we store in variables?

Comment: Use a temporary table

Comment: Sounds like an anti-pattern. For what do you want to store inserted records in variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `OUTPUT` `INTO` with a simple `INSERT` statement

What you will insert into table that will transferred to the another table

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes."